# constructor with deferred object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make good use of $.Deferred() to control the end of a async function. I also want some info returned from the function.

I setup something like this

```
var VideoInputOk2Start = new VideoInputStart();
    $.when(VideoInputOk2Start.Control).done(function () { console.log("SetUpVideoOK") });


    function VideoInputStart() {
        this.Control = $.Deferred();
        this.Ok = false;

if ( videoInput.paused == true ) {
    videoInput.play();
    this.Control.resolve();
    this.Ok = true;
}
    }
```

Is this approach correct? Or is there something more simple? Or am I making a error checking for VideoInputOk2Start.Control since it might not have been already created  by the constructor. 
some race condition mistake (anyway It works to my surprise)

Thanks

Comment: _"since it might not be created"_ What makes you say that?  It's assigned within the constructor function - it should never not be created?

Comment: i was thinking of some race condition, that the $.when(VideoInputOk2Start.Control) would be called before the constructor function

Comment: Whatever you are running at ```///async work``` should have a callback or be a promise.  A promise would chain to a resolver which you would then resolve your "Control" promise within your resolver function.  If using a callback you would resolve the promise within the callback.  Otherwise, you are currently resolving your promise before your work is done in the current structure.  Also, if you do use a promise there it would likely just be best to set ```this.Control``` equal to whatever promise is returned from that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you listed your promise is resolving before any work would be done.  Presumably, some async function would either take a callback function or return a promise.  The resolver for your promise is running as if the code would wait at that "async" function which will not occur (unless you use a generator or some such method).  Instead below you can see some the structure you could use.

```js
function someConstructor(url) {
  this.OK = false; // This is somewhat unnecessary with promises as you can check the state of a promise
  this.Control = fetch(url) // Async function which returns promise
    .then(function(res) { // Resolver function
      this.OK = true; // Set OK after promise is completed
    }.bind(this)); // bind 'this' to anonymous function
  console.log('Constructor has completed running');
}

var x = new someConstructor('http://i.imgur.com/63xpOZkb.jpg');

x.Control.then(function(res) {
  console.log("I am running only after async work is completed");
  document.write('completed download');
});
console.log("I am running after declaration of resolution function");
```

When running the above code take a look at the statements written to the console with console.log.  The code which is contained within the resolver functions only runs after the promise is completed.  This is where you would change some state.  If you notice the statement at the bottom of the code is run before the async work is complete.  This is showing why you can not have your code as you do (with .resolve() run immediately after your 'async' work).

Comment: dont you need to define this.Control has a deferred object?

Comment: fetch is a function which returns a promise.  So yes, the returned deferred object (promise) which is returned from "fetch()" in the example above is what defines the "this.Control" property.

Comment: You could use $.get as well.  Jquery has promises which you can use as well as other libraries.  Promises also are part of the standard now but are not implemented in all browsers.  I would recommend sticking to something as close to standard as possible but it really depends on what you need and how you want to use it.